# DetailsList Component with custom scrollbar

Tags: css, office-ui-fabric, fluentui-react

At the following [link](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/JjKxoPe) is the basic implementation of `DetailsList` with [Sticky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/scrollablepane) *(fixed header)*.

What I'm trying to achieve is to replace **default scrollbar** with **custom scrollbar** and to keep the same functionality/behavior.
After implementation of **custom scrollbar** header is not sticky and that's the main problem.

Working example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bogdan-kfmcl?file=/src/index.tsx).

I tried the following libraries:
[ReactCustomScrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars),
[OverlayScrollbars](https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars).

Answer (score 1):

Using an external library to handle the styling of the scrollbars probably wraps your content in a div and causes `position: sticky` to stop working.

Probably your best bet is to try to style the scrollbars in the `ScrollablePane` directly. Something like:

```js
const sbWidth = 6;
const sbHeight = 6;
const sbBg = "pink";
const sbThumbBg = "red";
```

```
<ScrollablePane
  styles={{
    root: {
      selectors: {

        // Firefox
        ".ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer": {
          scrollbarWidth: sbWidth,
          scrollbarColor: `${sbThumbBg} ${sbBg}`
        },

        // Chrome, Edge, etc
        ".ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer::-webkit-scrollbar": {
          width: sbWidth,
          height: sbHeight
        },
        ".ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
          background: sbBg
        },
        ".ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
          background: sbThumbBg
        }
      }
    }
  }}
>
```

You can of course add more customizations.
Didn't test on Firefox but should work.

CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fluet-ui-custom-scrollbars-ygm07?file=/src/index.tsx

Styling scrollbars: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/

[image: Styled scrollbars]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion and working solution. I'm trying to avoid `css customization` this time. There is open issue at fluentui github for this as a feature: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/8302

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet to App.css and no need to *adjust* any DetailsList individually. Apply the width/color that works best for you.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: #eee
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: #eeecec
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #dddcdc
}
```